# JTA aware JDBC connection pools

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, jta

I've been looking at a number of JDBC connection pools, but I have the specific requirement that the pool needs to be JTA aware, which leaves me with a short list of Apache DBCP and OW2 XAPool. The other pools I looked (c3p0, Proxool, BoneCP) at did not appear to satisfy the JTA requirement.

Does anyone have a recommendation about either XAPool, DBCP, or a connection pool I have not mentioned here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some standalone transaction managers like Atomikos or Bitronix have their own integrated connection pool. Such a pool is JTA compliant and would solve your problem.

Recently I was facing the same problem and finally I ended up with Bitronix and its integrated connection pool. It works well.

Comment: Ended up trying Atomikos with an integrated pool. The reason for the question was I was trying to find a pool that would work with JbossTS.

Answer (score 0):

If timelines permit and there's this requirement, I can add JTA support to BoneCP if you want.

Wallace
(BoneCP author)

Comment: One vote for that requirement in BoneCP: We use BasicManagedDataSource now (dbcp) that is buggy and and nobody seems to take care about the contributed patches.